# Cannot create a new Date() object from a date that contain milisec '2015-05-14 08:08:48.792'

Tags: javascript, datetime, firefox

```
   var newDate= new Date('2015-05-14 08:08:48.792');
   console.log(newDate);
```

If I run the code above I get the following: `Date {Invalid Date}`.
I have this problem in firefox, in chrome it works.

[image]

I need to create this object because I need to do difference between two dates that contains milliseconds. 
e.g. '2015-05-14 08:08:48.792' - '2015-05-14 08:08:50.792'

Comment: I don't think so. It is working fine. https://jsfiddle.net/7tkmjszv/

Comment: When I run it, i get: `Thu, 14 May 2015 06:08:48 GMT`.

Comment: For me doesn't work. I added a print screen.

Comment: I tried with Chrome, and it's working, but in firefox not

Answer (score 2):

You should be using a recognised format when dealing with date strings.

If you look at the Mozilla documentation for the Date constructor, the dateString overload accepts a string representing the date formatted as it would be valid for Date.parse().

Date:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Date.Parse:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

I would suggest *ISO8601* as it is generally more supported; 
`'2015-05-14T08:08:48.792Z'`. Notice the `T` indicating the start of the time segment of the pattern, and preferably the ending `Z` indicating this is in UTC time.

```
var newDate = new Date('2015-05-14T08:08:48.792Z');
document.write(newDate);
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7tkmjszv/1/

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Some javascript implementations are more broad and try to work out the format for you. Though ISO8601 is the safest way. If your input string is out of your control, could I suggested transforming it to ISO8601 before hand?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can use that Date String format for a New Date in JS.
Try to parse and

```
var newDate = new Date('2015', '05', '14', '08', '08', '48', '792');
```